# Dynamically increasing C string's size

Tags: c, string, memory-leaks, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm currently creating a program that captures user's keypresses and stores them in a string. I wanted the string that stores the keypresses to be dynamic, but i came across a problem.
My current code looks something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Foo {
  const char* str;
  int size;
} Foo;

int main(void)
{
  int i;
  Foo foo;
  foo.str = NULL;
  foo.size = 0;

  for (;;) {
    for (i = 8; i <= 190; i++) {
      if (GetAsyncKeyState(i) == -32767) { // if key is pressed
        foo.str = (char*)realloc(foo.str, (foo.size + 1) * sizeof(char)); // Access violation reading location xxx
        sprintf(foo.str, "%s%c", foo.str, (char)i);
        foo.size++;
      }
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, as I don't have any ideas anymore. :( 
Should I maybe also allocate the Foo object dynamically?

Comment: `sprintf(foo.str, "%s%c", foo.str, (char)i);`. Ask yourself - what is the content in `foo.str` when that is called? If the answer is not "a valid NUL terminated C string" every time then the behaviour is undefined. And you don't have to look far - even just do that exercise for the very first call.

Comment: Just as a side note: As stated in the documentation for [`GetAsyncKeyState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate), you should not be using the least-significant bit of the return value, as it is unreliable and only exists for backwards compatibility with 16-bit Windows.

Comment: Just as a side note: Using `GetAsyncKeyState` in a [busy-wait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) is not a good way to wait for user input, as this will cause 100% CPU usage on one CPU, preventing other threads and processes from using that CPU. It will also increase power consumption. If you are writing a graphical Windows application, you should create a proper message loop. If you are writing a Windows Console Application, you should use [`ReadConsoleInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleinput) instead.

Comment: Aside: if `realloc()` fails you leak memory. Always use a tmp pointer to validate the result of `realloc()`, and **only** assign it back to your main pointer on success (on failure your main pointer will still be there, and it's then up to you how to handle the error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `const char *str`  - you declare the pointer to `const char`. You cant write to the referenced object as it invokes UB
2. You use `sprintf` just to add the `char`. It makes no sense.
3. You do not need a pointer in the structure.

You need to set compiler options to compile **as C language" not C++
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9V1pt.png]

I would do it a bit different way:

```
typedef struct Foo {
    size_t size;
    char str[1];
} Foo;

Foo *addCharToFoo(Foo *f, char ch);
{
    if(f)
    {
        f = realloc(f, sizeof(*f) + f -> size);
    }
    else
    {
        f = realloc(f, sizeof(*f) + 1);
        if(f) f-> size = 0
    }
    if(f) //check if realloc did not fail
    {
        f -> str[f -> size++] = ch;
        f -> str[f -> size] = 0;
    }
    return f;
}
```

and in the `main`

```
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    Foo *foo = NULL, *tmp;

    for (;;) 
    {
        for (i = 8; i <= 190; i++) 
        {
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(i) == -32767) { // if key is pressed
            if((tmp = addCharToFoo(f, i))
            {
                foo = tmp;
            }
            else
            /* do something - realloc failed*/
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My IDE gives me an error when i try to write the `char str[];` (incomplete type is not allowed) :/

Comment: @czarson Microsodt. They still did not implement the changes from the 1980

Comment: happily, it doesn't generate an error if i declare the array as the last element of the struct

Answer (score 3):

First, in order to handle things nicely, you need to define

```c
typedef struct Foo {
    char* str;
    int size
} Foo;
```

Otherwise, Foo is really annoying to mutate properly - you invoke undefined behaviour by modifying `foo->str` after the realloc call in any way.

The seg fault is actually caused by `sprintf(foo.str, "%s%c", foo.str, (char)i);`, not the call to `realloc`. `foo.str` is, in general, not null-terminated.

In fact, you're duplicating work by calling `sprintf` at all. `realloc` already copies all the characters previously in `f.str`, so all you have to do is add a single character via

```c
f.str[size] = (char) i;
```

Edit to respond to comment:

If we wanted to append to strings (or rather, two Foos) together, we could do that as follows:

```c
void appendFoos(Foo* const first, const Foo* const second) {
    first->str = realloc(first->str, (first->size + second->size) * (sizeof(char)));
    memcpy(first->str + first->size, second->str, second->size);
    first->size += second->size;
}
```

The `appendFoos` function modifies `first` by appending `second` onto it.

Throughout this code, we leave `Foos` as non-null terminated. However, to convert to a string, you must add a final null character after reading all other characters.

Comment: it is still not the C string

Comment: @0___________ What do you mean? We're not trying to make it a C string.

Comment: @MarkSaving: `"We're not trying to make it a C string"` -- This statement seems incorrect. Quote from the question: `"I'm currently creating a program that captures user's keypresses and stores them in a string."`

Comment: @0___________ It is indeed possible because `f.str` points to an allocation of `size + 1` bytes. The cast may not be necessary, but it is definitely beneficial for clarity.

Comment: @0___________ How does this evoke undefined behaviour?

Comment: @MarkSaving `Dynamically increasing C string's size` **C string**.

Comment: @MarkSaving explicit casts may silence the warnings. Oly use the when **absolutely** necessary. Casting everything is a very bad practice.

Comment: @0___________ Thanks for your advice. I didn't even consider that OP would make `foo.str` a `const char*` rather than a `char*` since mutating via `foo.str` is such an integral part of OP's strategy.

Answer (score 0):

`sprintf(foo.str, "%s%c", foo.str, (char)i);` is ill-formed: the first argument cannot be `const char *`. You should see a compiler error message.

After fixing this (make `str` be `char *`),  then the behaviour is undefined because the source memory read by the `%s` overlaps with the destination.

Instead you would need to use some other method to append the character that doesn't involve overlapping read and writes (e.g. use the `[ ]` operator to write the character and don't forget about null termination).